# Mixing amplified signals of a 2.1 amp and outputting them to 2 speakers

Tags: amplifier, audio

I would like to mix the dedicated bass output of [this amp](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/NEW-TPA3116-high-power-HIFI-digital-power-amplifier-board-12-24-v-2-1-overweight-subwoofer/32814101644.html) with both the left and right channels and output the respective combined signal (L+bass, R+bass) on a set of two 200W, 4 Ohm speakers.

A quick search on this topic revealed it could be accomplished with an inverted OP amp, however, I am not sure whether this is a good idea as I do not need further amplification - the signals are already amplified. As I am not particularly well-versed in the realm of electronics, I would appreciate any advice on the topic.

Comment: An opamp could be used to manipulate small signals before you send them through a power amp, not after.

Comment: Would a simple resistive circuit suffice perhaps? If so, would I need to look for a specific resistor wattage rating at say a combined output of 100W?

Comment: A 2-way passive crossover works just as well in reverse as the intended forward direction. It won’t split your bass output though, but perhaps you could device a way to make it work. It will in the end not be worth it though compared to just getting a different amplifier.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Why do you need to mix the 2.1 output? Instead, simply amplify the stereo input and feed it to your stereo speakers.

Comment: The reason behind my question is that I feel like I am missing the bass in the stereo output. Is it possible to tell from the amplifier design whether the bass is separated/cut off from the L and R channels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question from the OP as seen in the comments:

> The reason behind my question is that I feel like I am missing the
>   bass in the stereo output. Is it possible to tell from the amplifier
>   design whether the bass is separated/cut off from the L and R
>   channels?

The original link provided seems to indicate that this amplifier is based on the TI TPA3116 chip. Which you can find the [technical documents here](http://www.ti.com/product/TPA3116D2/technicaldocuments) and the [PDF here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa3116d2.pdf)

Based on the datasheet, page 26, figure 37 "Schematic"; it seems that the components are wired to be in "master/slave" configuration to produce a 2.1 amplifier using 2 chips.

The bass is indeed seperated before amplification. This means that you do not have a bass in the 50+50 W stereo output. Without knowing the exact schematics of the actual board; I would not advise you to tamper with the electronics.

If you need a simple stereo amplifier, I would suggest that you source another board. Using the same site as the link indicates this shouldn't be hard nor costly.

I would not advise you to try to mix amplified signals to accomplish the same. While this may be accomplished using "reversed cross overs" this may be proven to be more costly than sourcing a stereo amplifier board.

Comment: Thank you Edwin for the detailed answer. I ended up doing exactly as you suggested.